# Error con imagen ASCII en bash

Tags: bash, script, ascii

Intento añadir un título con una imagen en un script que estoy creando. El problema es que el título aparece perfecto pero no sé como adaptar la imagen al echo.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "_                ___       _.--.  ______                 ______           _     ";
echo "\`.|\..----...-'`   `-._.-'_.-'`  | ___ \                | ___ \         | |    ";
echo "/  ' `         ,       __.--'     | |_/ / ___  __ _ _ __ | |_/ / __ _ ___| |__  ";
echo ")/' _/     \   `-_,   /           | ___ \/ _ \/ _\` | '_ \| ___ \/ _\` / __| '_ \ ";
echo "`-'" `"\_  ,_.-;_.-\_ ',          | |_/ /  __/ (_| | | | | |_/ / (_| \__ \ | | |";
echo "    _.-'_./   {_.'   ; /          \____/ \___|\__,_|_| |_\____/ \__,_|___/_| |_|";
echo "   {_.-``-'         {_/                                                         ";
echo "                                                                                ";
```

El resultado de esto es:

```
_                ___       _.--.  ______                 ______           _     
./bean.sh: command substitution: línea 17: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `|'
./bean.sh: command substitution: línea 17: `  | ___ \                | ___ \         | |    ";'
`.|\..----...-'-._.-'_.-'         ,       __.--'     | |_/ / ___  __ _ _ __ | |_/ / __ _ ___| |__  
./bean.sh: command substitution: línea 19: EOF inesperado mientras se buscaba un `'' coincidente
./bean.sh: command substitution: línea 21: error sintáctico: no se esperaba el final del fichero
./bean.sh: línea 19: \_  ,_.-;_.-\_ ',          | |_/ /  __/ (_| | | | | |_/ / (_| \__ \ | | |: No existe el fichero o el directorio
./bean.sh: command substitution: línea 21: EOF inesperado mientras se buscaba un `"' coincidente
./bean.sh: command substitution: línea 22: error sintáctico: no se esperaba el final del fichero
./bean.sh: línea 23: -         {_/                                                         ";
echo "                                                                                ";

_                ___       _.--.
`.|\..----...-: No existe el fichero o el directorio
./bean.sh: línea 19: -._.-_.-: orden no encontrada
)/' _/     \   -' _.-'_./ {_.' ; / \____/ \___|\__,_|_| |_\____/ \__,_|___/_| |_|
```

¿Qué debería editar o añadir para que aparezca el gato en ASCII en el script?

Comment: Es que estás usando caracteres desquisiados. Mi recomendación rápida es que guardes todo en un archivo llamado `mi_banner_loco.ban`, y luego, dentro del script, lo leas.

Answer (score 0):

No uses caracteres como los de escape `\`, tampoco las comillas agudas `, debido a que lo que esté dentro se toma como si fuese un comando.

Otra opción, es guardar ese banner en un archivo, por ejemplo, `banner.txt`, y dentro de tu script lo llamas con `cat banner.txt`.